# How to safely inject props into React children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, element, children, react-props

I am building a React component which delays the unmounting of its children in order to animate them. When unmounting, I would like to pass in an additional prop (for example, a data-attribute or a class name) in order to handle animations.

This is a specific instance of a general situation where I want override certain properties of children. I have come to realize that the following pattern does exactly what I want:

```
this.props.children.map(child => 
    <child.type key={child.key} 
                ref={child.ref}
               {...child.props} 
               // add my props into children here
               data-leaving={true} />)
```

Instead of returning the child element, I return a new element of the same type and with the same props. I can then add or remove any props I want!

However, this is undocumented and feels very hacky. I would like to know if this is safe to use in every case.

Note that I am aware of alternatives (for example, accepting a function which returns the children instead of children directly) but this gives the most convenient interface by far.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Best way to add new props or override existing ones is to map your children props and clone each element using `React.cloneElement`.

Nice article to read about [react children](https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/).

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { newProp: 'value', existingProp: 'value' }));
```

You could also use children as a function. This way u can also add your props.

**Example:**

```
// Root Component
const Parent = () => { 
  const onClose = () => console.log('I am on Close Prop');

  // Pass OnClose to children
  return <MyComponent>{ children(onClose) }</MyComponent>
}

// MyComponent
const MyComponent = () => {
// Pass OnClose to children
  return (
    <div>
      {/* children below */}
      {(onClose) => (
          <FormComponent
              myNewProp={onClose}
          />
      )}
    </div>
);

}
```