# how to overwrite children's props in react

Tags: reactjs

i want to render a list of react components.The props of each component vary,but every element's props will be overwritten by parents props.i tried something like this

```
render(){
        let children=this.props.children
        let dis;
        if(Array.isArray(children)){
            dis=[]
            children.forEach(c=>{let l=Object.assign(c,Object.assign(c.props,this.props))
            dis.push(l)})

        }
        return(
            {dis}
        )

    }
}
```

but got error that props in read only.

Comment: `props` are readonly. please don't change them. if you need too then update them in the sub component via `setState`

Comment: I'm not really sure why this is necessary or what the use case is. I assume this component and its children are rendered together, so why not just adjust the props there?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is have a parent component inject additional settings into the children it is going to render.

Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786569/1541237

Basically, you would render like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, { ...this.props }));
  );
}
```